# How can an outlet work when the neutral and hot are not connected to the screws opposite each other on the same side?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I see this outlet that works but the neutral and hot are opposing. Both plugs work. How is this true?

[yellow is hot white is neutral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIi6R.jpg)

[image]

Comment: I found the solution in another thread [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/185346/replacing-and-outlet-2-plugs-with-only-one-black-one-white-has-ground-wire) Thanks all!

Answer (score 8):

Hot appears to be connected to the brass colored screw, as it should be, so you were evidently just unaware that the (removable when needed) links connecting the two halves of the outlet make the connection points on each side equivalent when they are unbroken.

[image]